# What are the odds that De Vries' formula for the fine structure constant $\alpha$ is a numerical coincidence?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, constants

The dimensionless fine structure constant $\alpha \approx \frac1{137}$ has intrigued physicists for over a century. Whilst not currently a majority view, there is a school of thought that considers this constant may have a mathematical origin, just like $\pi$ or $e$. Many researchers have indeed proposed formulas for $\alpha$ in the past (including on this [forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982160/how-can-one-decide-between-structure-or-coincidence-regarding-the-fine-structure)), all of which have progressively fallen outside of experimental bounds as the fine structure constant was measured with ever more precision.

In 1971, for example, Physics Today reviewed the work of Armand Wyler, who proposed $\alpha = (2^{19}3^{-7}5\pi^{11}5)^{1/4}$ yielding approximately 1/137.03608, which was close to the experimental value at the time of 1/137.03611 (21). The article elicited many replies, among which half a dozen of alternative combinations of powers of 2, 3, 5 and $\pi$ which all approximated $\alpha$ with similar precision, or better. One reader went on to show mathematically that Wyler's precision was not unusual, given the high integer powers used in the formula.

In 2004, Hans de Vries proposed a rather different type of formula for $\alpha$, which reads:
$$
\alpha \sqrt{e^{\pi^2}}=\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{(2\pi)^0}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{(2\pi)^1}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{(2\pi)^2}\left(1+...\right)\right)\right)\right)^2
$$

There's an intuitive appeal to this formula, as it uses only the expected mathematical constants and a minimum amount of free integers. Its value, 0.0072973525686..., is within experimental accuracy of the current recommended value at NIST: 0.0072973525693 (11).

My question is: what can we say about the likelihood that this is a numerical coincidence? For example, how straightforward would it be to construct another 'simple' infinite series that converges onto the same experimental value range?

---

---

The fine structure constant is measured more and more precisely by different methods every so often. The value mentioned here is the current recommended value from NIST at the time of writing. The latest NIST value may be accessed [online](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?alph).

See also this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3159665/1112784) to a related question, where the user states

> If you can find a **simple** mathematical recipe to arrive at this constant, this would be noteworthy.

---

*The Fine-Structure Constant: From Eddington's Time to Our Own*, Jacob. D. Bekenstein in The Prism of Science, 1986.

*A mathematician's version of the fine structure constant*, Gloria Lubkin in Physics Today, August 1971

*A new pastime — calculating alpha to one part in a million*, Letters to the editor in Physics Today, November 1971

Comment: Is that equation intended to be *solved* for $\alpha$?

Comment: One possible approach: The approximation, to the point that it is no longer correct, has about $30$ bits of content. Would it take more or less than $30$ bits to express that equation? There's a fair amount of redundancy, but I'm not confident of being able to assess that. I'll have to give it some thought. ETA: I wonder if anyone's done any research into entropy and/or Huffman coding of mathematics expressions.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes it is meant to be solved for α. One can try this on Wolfram Alpha: α√e^π²=∑[α^n/(2π)^(½n(n-1)),n=0..3]², which produces α to within experimental accuracy. (Same formula, rewritten as 'infinite' sum. Not sure if that increases/decreases the entropy of the equation...)

Comment: The *appeal* of a simple, neat formula is never a good argument for its truth. The Monster group is a good example of a very simple concept (groups) yielding insane numbers and formulas when characterized.  
There are of course infinitely many infinite series approximating $\alpha$ arbitrarily well. I find it hard to believe you could find a "simpleness" criteria that would reduce this to finitely many that would not be very likely to exclude reasonable possible answers.

Comment: Pallas, what gets squared on the right-hand side of your summation form? The entire summation, or just the summand?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim you are of course right in a mathematical sense and this probably applies to all the laws of physics. I guess the trick is to find the 'simplest' way of describing the observed phenomena, until the next scientific revolution... 
(I just added the 'soft-question' tag to highlight the intuitive part).

Comment: @BrianTung The whole sum. Indeed it's a bit ambiguous as written - I tried reducing the size of the formula on Wolfram Alpha, which (surprisingly?) still interprets this in the way it was meant... 
(For completeness sake, the '3' is just there to make it tractable for WA, the mathematical form should read ∞).

Answer (score 5):

Based on an back-of-the-envelope information-theoretical calculation, I don't think there's anything particularly surprising here. The measured value and the solution to that expression for $\alpha$ share $9$ digits. That implies about $9 \log_2 10 \approx 30$ bits of information.

Compare that with the parse tree of the expression (I used your summation form). The way I construct it—maybe I'll draw it out and paste it in, but I doubt it, haha—it has $29$ nodes. These nodes contain things like

- constants such as $e, \pi, 2, \ldots$
- operators such as the four arithmetic operations, exponentiation, square root, summation
- $\alpha$ and the dummy variable $n$
- the equality relation

Even optimized for their frequency in this particular expression, this tree requires at least $62$ bits to encode. The fact that it produces $30$ bits of accuracy is therefore unsurprising. That doesn't mean that it isn't "correct" (whatever that means), but its correctness should not be presumed on probabilistic grounds.

Comment: A very interesting approach - thanks! We might be able to chip off another handful of bits by rewriting the formula in an even more compact way, but I guess we'll have to wait until α is experimentally known to at least another 9 digits before this path becomes convincing... 
It's a bit of an open question so I'm keen to see others' perspectives as well.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: would this form need exactly the same number of bits to encode?
α√e^π²=∑[(α√(2π)^(1-n))^n,n=0..3]²
(It's the shortest Wolfram Alpha formulation I could come up with).

Comment: @Pallas: It saves three nodes. It would change the frequencies, so the bits per node would change somewhat, but assuming it doesn't change too much, I imagine you could shave things down to maybe $56$ bits.